# How to achieve a sequence of numbers each iteration in arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

We try to create a sequence of numbers so that the numbers in each matrix continue to the previous matrix. Unfortunately, I don't always succeed, can anyone help me with that?

Here I set the condition that the first line starts from the maximum number in the field, and in the following the sequence of numbers starts from the last value of the previous arrays. But for some reason, each matrix starts from the first field
Can anyone advise me on this?

```
#condition that if the first line is a condition, the condition is used
        if p==1:
             l=np.arange(maxv,end)
             arr=l.reshape(frst,n)
#the next lines I take the last number from the previous matrix and the initial sequence of numbers of the next matrix
        else:
            l=np.arange(end,end1)
            arr=l.reshape(frst,n)
        print(arr,'\n')
        #print(p) #counter
```

My output:

```
[[ 9. 10. 11. 12. 13.]
 [14. 15. 16. 17. 18.]
 [19. 20. 21. 22. 23.]] 

[[15. 16. 17.]
 [18. 19. 20.]] 

[[15. 16. 17.]
 [18. 19. 20.]]
```

required output

```
[[ 9. 10. 11. 12. 13.]
 [14. 15. 16. 17. 18.]
 [19. 20. 21. 22. 23.]] 

[[24. 25. 26.]
 [27. 28. 29.]] 

[[30. 31. 32.]
 [33. 34. 35.]]
```

demofile.txt

```
>=3 4 1 6 7 5
>=2 1 3 2
>=2 -2 -5 -8
```

full code with comments

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import math

#remove first word in each line from demofile
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
with open('output.txt', mode='w',newline='\n') as output:
    for i in list(lines):
        #remove operators and first number from demofile
        sfn = i.split(" ", 1)
        newfilename = sfn[1]
        output.write(newfilename)

#getmax value from demofile        
inputFile = open('output.txt', 'r')
num_list = [float(num) for num in inputFile.read().split()]
max_val = max(num_list)
min_val = min(num_list)  
absmin=abs(min_val)
absmax=abs(max_val)
maxv=max(absmin,absmax)

#print(maxv)     


with open("demofile.txt", "r") as s:
    
    #read data
    f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    #input preprocessing
    p=1
    
    for i in list(lines):
        
        if i[0] != '<' and i[0] != '>' and i[0] != '=':
            d = str(' '.join(i.split()))
            print(d)
                
        else:
            w = i.replace("=",'')
            w = w.replace(">",'')
            w = w.replace("<",'')
            w = ', '.join(w.split())
            c=np.array([w])            
            c1 = [int(i) for i in c[0].replace(" ", "").split(",")]
             #insert input to array
            c1=np.array(c1)
            # save first value in array
            frst=c1[0]
             #remove first value in array
            c1=np.delete(c1, 0)       
            #count values in line 
            n=len(c1)
            #max value from demofile
            maxv=maxv+1
            #last numbers
            end=frst*n+maxv
            #create sequence of numbers
            l=np.arange(maxv,end)
            #create array
            arr=l.reshape(frst,n)
            #last numbers from array
            last_num=arr[-1,-1]+1
            #new start numbers for following arrays           
            end1=end+frst*n
    #condition that if the first line is a condition, the condition is used
            if p==1:
                 l=np.arange(maxv,end)
                 arr=l.reshape(frst,n)
    #the next lines I take the last number from the previous matrix and the initial sequence of numbers of the next matrix
            else:
                l=np.arange(end,end1)
                arr=l.reshape(frst,n)
            print(arr,'\n')
            #print(p) #counter
            p+=1
```

Comment: I haven't tried to follow the over all logic, but if you keep track of the arguments to `np.arange(start,end)` correctly, it should work.  That is, the `start` of the next call should be the `end` of the previous.  It should be simple matter of updating the variables correctly.  Print intermediate values if necessary.  Often guessing is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract your generation as a callable object that knows how to generate a matrix by counting from a given value `end`, and update the value every time it generates a matrix so that the next start from the updated value

```py
class CountingArrays:
    def __init__(self, e0=1):
        self.end = e0
    def __call__(self, *shape):
        N = np.prod(shape);
        self.end += N
        return np.arange(self.end-N, self.end).reshape(shape)
```

Once you have this, it is very natural to produce the matrices you described

```py
# Construct the C callable, that will start the first matrix
# with the value 9
C = CountingArrays(9)
# Generate the matrices with the shapes of the matrices you listed.
print(C(3,5))
print(C(2,3))
print(C(2,3))
```

Output:

```
[[ 9 10 11 12 13]
 [14 15 16 17 18]
 [19 20 21 22 23]]
[[24 25 26]
 [27 28 29]]
[[30 31 32]
 [33 34 35]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are the corrected version of your own code. The problem was that in the second cycle you were modifying the "end" number you had found in the previous cycle before using it.

BUT THERE ARE SURELY BETTER WAYS TO WRITE THIS CODE!!!

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import math

# remove first word in each line from demofile
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()
with open('output.txt', mode='w', newline='\n') as output:
    for i in list(lines):
        # remove operators and first number from demofile
        sfn = i.split(" ", 1)
        newfilename = sfn[1]
        output.write(newfilename)

# getmax value from demofile
# inputFile = open('output.txt', 'r')
# num_list = [float(num) for num in inputFile.read().split()]
# max_val = max(num_list)
# min_val = min(num_list)
# absmin = abs(min_val)
# absmax = abs(max_val)
# maxv = max(absmin, absmax)
maxv = abs(max(num_list, key=abs))

# print(maxv)


with open("demofile.txt", "r") as s:
    # read data
    f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    # input preprocessing
    p = 1

    for i in list(lines):

        if i[0] != '<' and i[0] != '>' and i[0] != '=':
            d = str(' '.join(i.split()))
            print(d)

        else:
            w = i.replace("=", '')
            w = w.replace(">", '')
            w = w.replace("<", '')
            w = ', '.join(w.split())
            c = np.array([w])
            c1 = [int(i) for i in c[0].replace(" ", "").split(",")]
            # insert input to array
            c1 = np.array(c1)
            # save first value in array
            frst = c1[0]
            # remove first value in array
            c1 = np.delete(c1, 0)
            # count values in line
            n = len(c1)
            # max value from demofile
            maxv = maxv + 1
            # condition that if the first line is a condition, the condition is used
            if p == 1:
                # last numbers
                end = frst * n + maxv
                l = np.arange(maxv, end)
                arr = l.reshape(frst, n)
            # the next lines I take the last number from the previous matrix and the initial sequence of numbers of the next matrix
            else:
                # new start numbers for following arrays
                end1 = end + frst * n
                l = np.arange(end, end1)
                arr = l.reshape(frst, n)
                end = end1
            print(arr, '\n')
            # print(p) #counter
            p += 1
```